# How to send out a collection of nodes via neo4j-stream to kafka

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka, stream, cypher

We want to use Neo4J to build a hierarchy (tree-structure) of (product) categories. Our data enters from a Kafka (Sink Connector). We plan to use Neo4J Streams Source to live stream the updates on our category-tree back onto Kafka, using neo4j-4.0.3.

Normally, the - Streams Source - way to go is to specify a pattern and link it to a Kafka topic, as explained here: https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/#neo4j_streams_source

In order to leverage the power of Neo4J we'd like to send a collection of nodes *each time at once*. This collection consists of all the nodes on a - query that returns a - path: `nodes(path)`. More specifically, such a collection of nodes represents a path from leaf to root.

Two non-working alternatives we could think of:

1. **Use a pattern definition.** From what I understand a pattern seems to be limited to match a single node only (possibly a node with multiple Labels) - https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/#source-patterns - and hence we can only stream out *one node at a time*.
2. **Stream the collection of nodes** (on the path) back **into a node** with a different label, and use that output node label to pattern match {*}. Neo4J being a property oriented graph database, it does not allow me to write 'a collection of nodes' into one node.

To summarize, what we want is to stream out a collection of nodes into each Kafka record.
**Any suggestions on how we can achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [streams.publish procedure](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/procedure/#_streams_publish) will send any arbitrary data that you can format with Cypher to the topic of your choosing.  It's just up to you to format the data as you wish.

I'm imagining something like this:

```
MATCH (a:MyLabel { id: 'startingPoint' })
WITH a
MATCH p=shortestPath((a)-[:REL*]->(b:MyLabel { id: 'EndingPoint' }))
UNWIND nodes(p) as node
WITH collect({ 
    my: 'custom-object',
    prop: node.prop
}) as recordsToSendToKafka
CALL streams.publish('my-topic', recordsToSendToKafka)
```

This would send an array of JSON records formatted as you choose, from the original matched path.

Note that using APOC triggers, you can do these kinds of things *in response to other transactions within Neo4j*, and so this doesn't have to be a one-and-done manual execute query pattern.

tl;dr if you can match anything out of the database, you can use cypher to reformat it into JSON objects and dispatch any data to any topic on Kafka.